# When do i have to use the fit method of scikit learn?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, svm

I do not understand when I have to use the fit method of scikit learn.

In this web page: http://machinelearningmastery.com/automate-machine-learning-workflows-pipelines-python-scikit-learn/ 
there is an example with a pipeline + StandardScaler. The fit method is not used.

But in this other one: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_rbf_parameters.html
there is also a StandardScaler and there is a fit method.

This is my code: Pipeline+Robustscaler:

```
result_list = []

for name in ["AWA","Rem","S1","S2","SWS","SX", "ALL"]: 
    x=sio.loadmat('/home/{}_E.mat'.format(name))['x'] 
    s_y=sio.loadmat('/home/{}_E.mat'.format(name))['y']
    y=np.ravel(s_y)

    print(name, x.shape, y.shape) 
    print("")

    #Create a pipeline
    clf = make_pipeline(preprocessing.RobustScaler(), SVC(cache_size=1000, kernel='rbf'))


    ###################10x20 SSS##################################
    print("10x20")
    xSSSmean20 = []
    for i in range(10):
        sss= StratifiedShuffleSplit(y, 20, test_size=0.1, random_state=i)
        scoresSSS=cross_validation.cross_val_score(clf, x, y, cv=sss)

        xSSSmean20.append(scoresSSS.mean()) 

     result_list.append(xSSSmean20)

     print("")
```

Comment: Why is it a bad question?

Comment: Because `The fit method is not used.` is a wrong statement. It is used in `cross_val_score`

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I did not know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To **train** your classifier you **must** fit it into your training data set.

The first link does it also, it is not because it does not appear explicitly in the snippet that it does not do it :

The method `cross_val_score` uses  `model` which is the estimator to **fit** it to the data.

Take a look to the implementation of the method 'cross_val_score' and try to understand how it works instead of using it without understanding what it does.

[Here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html) is the documentation of the function and [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/412996f/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py#L37) the implementation in **GitHub** to refer to.

Piece of advice :

Try to go dig in the code when you don't understand something. You'll learn a lot !